# going back from target blank .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this code working, When I click a link, it goes back to the previous page, however if I use target blank I cant go back.

Is there any way to go back a page using target blank?

This is my code

```
  <input type="button" value="Return to Pharmacy Future" onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;" class="disclaimerbtn" /><asp:Button runat="server" id="thirdPartyBtn" Text="Continue to third party site" CssClass="disclaimerbtn"></asp:Button></p>
</asp:Content>
```

This lets me go back to a link when clicking a button, but with target blank it doesn't allow this.

because it works in all pages. i just want it to happen in 1 occasion, basically i have pretty photo pop up, and that takes me to another link using target blank. http://pharmacyfutures.anytimeafter9.co.uk/

check Adverse Event Reporting

Comment: This is general to browsers and HTML. You might get better response by tagging it that way and taking out references to .NET since it appears that has nothing to do with the actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sort of guessing that you are interested in opening the previous page, but doing that in a new browser window. The following code works *so long as `document.referrer` contains the url you are looking for* (not always the case):

```
<a onclick="window.open(document.referrer, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');">Previous Page</a>
```

Best of luck!

Comment: because it works in all pages. i just want it to happen in 1 occasion, basically i have pretty photo pop up, and that takes me to another link using target blank. http://pharmacyfutures.anytimeafter9.co.uk/
check Adverse Event Reporting

Comment: If I inspect element and add `target="_blank"` on that link it works fine. Try that.